# Function taking only natural values

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[ 0,1 ] \to \mathbb N$ be a continuous function. Show that $f$ is a constant function.

As $f$ is continuous it follows the Ivp hence between two values $f (a)$ and $f (b)$ there must exist one $f (c)$ belongs to $\mathbb N$ but this is not possible.

But the above argument is false since $\mathbb N$ is discrete set. 
Please help!

Comment: How I'd answer this depends on context a little. What course are you doing? Is it, say, a real analysis course? A topology course?

Comment: Real analysis  class

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous then since $[0,1]$ is connected it follows that $f([0,1])$ is connected. The only connected, non empty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are singletons.

Comment: Without connectedness

Comment: It is a good idea to add relevant constraints to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your argument suffices, although it's very difficult to tell without knowing your instructor and their expectations. In a real analysis class, the function $f$ is just a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, whose range happens to lie in $\mathbb{N}$. The same logic works: if $f$ is non-constant, then there exist distinct integers $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = m$ and $f(y) = n$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $m + 0.1$ or $m - 0.1$ must lie between $m$ and $n$, and is not an integer. By the IVT, there must be some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(z) = m \pm 0.1$, which is a contradiction.

If this were a topology class instead, it might be good to put a note about how the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is the subspace topology when considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Consequently, we can extend $f$ to a function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose continuity is equivalent to the continuity of $f$. From there, the IVT argument works to show $g$ is continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.